# how to display recently viewed products in cms block and call it in details page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanted to display the recently viewed products in the `cms/block` and call it in product details page.

This is the line I gave in `cms/block`:

`<p>{{block type="reports/product_viewed"template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}</p>`

And in `view.phtml` I included this part:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_details_tab')->toHtml() ?>
```

But nothing is getting displayed. Where have I went wrong?

Comment: <p>{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}</p>

Answer (score 2):

call this in your phtml instead

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: No exactly I want to display the recently viewed products inside a `tab` content in `cmsblock` . So that is the reason i want to give it in block and then call in `view.phtml`

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok

```
 1. Do Re-Indexing from Admin > System > Index Management.
```

```
 2. Refresh Statics from Admin > Report > Products > Most Viewed.
```

```
 3. Check Recently Viewed/Compared Products count from 
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Recently Viewed/Compared Products
```

```
 4. Refresh Cache
```

Now try.